# JTable - AutoRowSorter - getColumnClass - not working

Tags: java, swing, model, jtable

In my Table Model I have an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>` which contains my data.

The data has been read in from a .csv file, each record is of the form:

> 7.68573749,-8.551567,21,276,AUD,AAA,7.224,1002,250,AUD Eurobonds Secondary,01/02/1996,T00001

I tried to read in each cell with the appropriate type but, for example, `7.68573749` would not read in with the scanner method `nextDouble()`. So everything is read in as `String` by default.

So my TableModel extends `AbstractTableModel`, and I have overridden the `getColumnClass` method, using an array of Class types hardwired in, with the `getColumnClass(int col)` returning the appropriate Class etc

Unfortunately, I still cannot set each cell to be the appropriate type as I get errors: 
cannot render Object as Number, when trying to use Double.Class.

I can however set everything to be either String or Integer.

But even with that, the `AutoRowSorter` still sorts every column by String only.

I can post code, but there is a lot of code and I can provide it when asked specifically what is needed.

Any help would be great, thanks, the ultimate goal here is to be able to sort the table data correctly

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set column's Datatype as double  , then convert the String numbers into Double using Double.valueOf() and simultaneously insert it into the JTable

example

```
for(int i=0;i<ss.length;i++)
  {
   table_model_object.addRow(i,Double.valueOf(ss[i]);
   }
```

Comment: He's not using the default table model, but his own TableModel. But using `Double.valueOf` is a valuable suggestion.

Comment: Yes, I have actually tried this before and it did not work. I believe there were errors complaining that it could not display things properly - I will quickly try this again and report back the actual error

Comment: Alright so datas is an ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>, data is the same except it holds the actual data for my table model.

http://pastebin.com/bwTfWSkH

I then run this code to run through datas and to setup data, with the appropriate class types now set.

But apparently everything in data is STILL a String, why?

Comment: Well I think I figured out the problem. I am working on top of a lot of ancient Java code that was written before Java generics time and I think it threw everything off - I wasn't aware it would of caused so many problems